# Selenium's version of seleniumwire's requests

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dependencies

So, originally my code was something like this:

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=self.web_options
driver.get(user_site)
ret = list(driver.requests)
verify = extract_verify(ret)
driver.requests.clear()
driver.get(self.root + '?verify={}'.format(urllib.parse.quote(verify)))
resp = self.driver.page_source
```

The api has changed so that `driver.get` needs to be replaced with `driver.request('POST', root, data={"verify": urllib.parse.quote(verify)})` which requires me to install `seleniumrequests`, but `seleniumrequests` is built on the selenium webdriver, not the seleniumwire webdriver and if I try to switch out the webdriver, then the driver.requests line doesn't work because selenium doesn't have that field.

As for versions, I have:

```
selenium=4.6.0
selenium-wire=5.1.0
selenium-requests=2.0.1
Python=3.8.10
```

What do you guys think I should try?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this with `from seleniumrequests.request import RequestsSessionMixin`. It was still helpful to get my thoughts on paper like this.